# Appending csv in s3 inconsistent

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to process huge set of images in S3 and wanted to append the file names of the images processed into a csv.

Below is the code snippet that I am trying to use

```
//Creating csv of file names
const getParams = {
    Bucket: `${processedImages}`,
    Key: 'processedImages.csv'
};
console.log('Reading csv file');
var content = '';
const csvCreation = await S3.getObject(getParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
        content = new Buffer.from(data.Body).toString("utf8");
        content = content + '\n' + srcKey; 
        console.log('Final content' + content);
        var putParams = {
            Body: content,
            Bucket: `${processedImages}`,
            Key: 'processedImages.csv',
            CacheControl: "no-cache"
         };
        console.log('Uploading csv file');
        S3.putObject(putParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else{
                console.log('Uploading complete');
                console.log(data);           // successful response
            }
         }).promise();
    }
}).promise();
await Promise.all([csvCreation]);
```

The created csv is always inconsistent and does not give the desired results.

Can someone please point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `The created csv is always inconsistent and does not give the desired results.` - we need more info. What do you exactly get and what you exactly expect?

Comment: The images are all processed fine and saved to target bucket. but all the file names of the images are not getting appended in the csv file.  Few of them are always getting missed out with no errors in logs

Comment: Few other times i have noticed when I test with fresh set of image uploads, the file names of the previous run are getting appended as part of next run. Just driving me nuts

Comment: Are you processing multiple images in parallel?

Comment: yes. it is a lambda trigger which processes multiple images in parallel based on put activity

Comment: Then there's a race condition.  Lambda call #1 will read the file from S3, then Lambda call #2 will read the same file.  They'll both add a line, and both will write the file with one new entry to S3, and only one can win.  You either need to write individual files to S3 that no call will overwrite, or store results in a database, or some other solution that doesn't involve the race condition.